# Discount option with decimal number returns incorrect value

Tags: php, decimal-point

I have 3 discount options for customers:

- 10%
- 12.5%
- 20%

10%, and 20% work fine, but the 12.5% option returns an incorrect 12%?

```
$getUserDiscount = "12.5%";
$getUserDiscount = str_replace('%', '', $getUserDiscount);
$percentage = "-0.$getUserDiscount";
$surcharge = $cart_contents_total * $percentage;
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why shouldn't it? you're doing `"-0.12.5"` which isn't eactly a legal number. when you do the multiplication, php corrects your error to `-0.12`

Comment: @MarcB Yep. What would you recommend? 0.125?

Comment: I'd suggest not storing your percentages as strings.

Comment: `$percentage = $getUserDiscount / 100.00;` ? PHP will do the correct thing.

Comment: $percentage=(-1)*$getUserDiscount/100; as per your logic

Answer (score 1):

You can change percentage values to decimal just by dividing by 100. So it will be like this for your problem :

```
$percentage = -1 * $getUserDiscount / 100;
```